# Convergence in measure: question about definition

Tags: measure-theory

In the definition of **convergence in measure** many authors say:

Let $f_n, f: E \to \overline {\mathbb R} = \mathbb R \cup \{\pm \infty\}$ be measurable and *almost everywhere finite* functions on $E$. If for any $\varepsilon > 0$
$$
\mu(\left\{x \in E: |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \varepsilon \right\}) \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{}0,
$$
then $f_n$ is called convergent in measure to $f$.

However, we can define that $(+\infty) - (+\infty) = (-\infty) + (+\infty) = 0$. Why do wee need then to ask $f_n, f$ to be almost everywhere finite?

Comment: We cannot just define $+\infty$-$(+\infty)$ to be 0, this is very ill-defined. For example $x$ and $e^x$ both tends to $+\infty$ but clearly one grows much faster than the other.

Comment: @FinnPillar, we are not talking about limits, we are talking about exact infinite values at a particular point

Comment: Convergence in measure is supposed to capture convergence on average. For example, if $f_n(x)=n$ and $f(x)=+\infty$ for all $x\in E$, then $f_n$ wouldn't converge in measure to $f$, but it certainly converges in any reasonable sense, so it wouldn't be a good idea to include this in the definition.

Comment: @Nick, awesome, thank you!

Comment: @user_on My point is that I don't think you can give a reasonable meaning to $\infty-\infty$ even for exact infinite values in the extended reals. Also, in the extended reals $+\infty=\lim x=\lim e^x$ as exact infinte values.